# I need to choose more values from some tasks that belong to same project

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

**My question is:** Is there any other method to select the values I need from all the tasks that belongs to same project and sum them?  Other method that I tried in the **down description**?

**Description:**

I have an app where I can create a Project and, inside the Project, I can create Tasks. For every Task, I can add a percent and calculate a price (example picture 1).

Then I have a report page where I want to calculate all the prices from all of the Tasks of same project (example picture 2).

My problem is when I want to select all the prices from all the tasks that belongs to same projects and sum them in the table "price" of report page.
For the moment I tried a method with the code I put down, and it's not working as I need, because it take the correct value from the first task of the project but dont take corect value from the ohther tasks from the same project

picture 1
[image: picture 1]

picture 2 (but here the problem is that just the first array is corrent the other are not)
[image]

code I use ( I commented in the code with "the code that doesnt work" the part that make the sum) :

```
<?php



defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');



$hasPermissionEdit   = has_permission('tasks', '', 'edit');

$hasPermissionDelete = has_permission('tasks', '', 'delete');

$tasksPriorities     = get_tasks_priorities();



$aColumns = [

    db_prefix() . 'tasks.id as id',

    db_prefix() . 'tasks.name as task_name',

    'count(tbltasks.id) as totaltasks',

    //'(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ",") FROM ' . db_prefix() . 'tasks) as itemlist',

];



$sIndexColumn = 'id';

$sTable       = db_prefix() . 'tasks';



$where = [];

$join  = [];

$sGroupBy = ' group by '.db_prefix() . 'tasks.rel_id';



// =============== Filter =================

    if (isset($ts_filter_data['period-from']) && $ts_filter_data['period-from'] != '' && isset($ts_filter_data['period-to']) && $ts_filter_data['period-to'] != '') {



        $ts_filter_from          = to_sql_date($ts_filter_data['period-from']);

        $ts_filter_from          = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ts_filter_from));

        $ts_filter_to            = to_sql_date($ts_filter_data['period-to']);

        $ts_filter_to            = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ts_filter_to));

    }



    if (isset($ts_filter_data['this_month']) && $ts_filter_data['this_month'] != '') {

        $ts_filter_from = date('Y-m-01'); 

        $ts_filter_to  = date('Y-m-t 23:59:59');

    }



    if (isset($ts_filter_data['last_month']) && $ts_filter_data['last_month'] != '') {

        $ts_filter_from = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-1 MONTH'));; 

        $ts_filter_to  = date('Y-m-t 23:59:59', strtotime('-1 MONTH'));

    }



    if (isset($ts_filter_data['this_week']) && $ts_filter_data['this_week'] != '') {

        $ts_filter_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week'));

        $ts_filter_to  = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('sunday this week'));

    }



    if (isset($ts_filter_data['last_week']) && $ts_filter_data['last_week'] != '') {

        $ts_filter_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday last week'));

        $ts_filter_to  = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('sunday last week'));

    }



    if($ts_filter_from){

        array_push($where, 'AND '.db_prefix().'tasks.startdate >="'.$ts_filter_from.'"');

    }



    if($ts_filter_to){

        array_push($where, 'AND '.db_prefix().'tasks.startdate <="'.$ts_filter_to.'"');

    }



// =============== Filter =================



array_push($where, 'AND '.db_prefix().'tasks.rel_type="project"');

// Script By Dev Websyms

$aColumns = hooks()->apply_filters('tasks_table_sql_columns', $aColumns);



// Fix for big queries. Some hosting have max_join_limit

if (count($custom_fields) > 4) {

    @$this->ci->db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');

}



$result = data_tables_init(

    $aColumns,

    $sIndexColumn,

    $sTable,

    $join,

    $where,

    [

        'tbltasks.rel_type',

        'tbltasks.rel_id',

        'tbltasks.task_item_percentage',

        'tbltasks.task_duration',

        tasks_rel_name_select_query() . ' as rel_name',



        get_sql_select_task_assignees_ids() . ' as assignees_ids',



        '(SELECT staffid FROM ' . db_prefix() . 'task_assigned WHERE taskid=' . db_prefix() . 'tasks.id AND staffid=' . get_staff_user_id() . ') as is_assigned',

    ],

    $sGroupBy

);



$output  = $result['output'];

$rResult = $result['rResult'];



$loop = 1;

foreach ($rResult as $aRow) {

    $row = [];

    $projectTaskIds = get_assign_project_task($aRow['rel_id']);

    $assignees_ids = $aRow['assignees_ids'];

    $assignees_id = explode(',', $assignees_ids);

    $calA = get_task_user_hourly_rate($assignees_id[0]); // hourly_rate


    if($projectTaskIds && count($projectTaskIds)){

    $realTime = 0;
    $estimateCost = 0;
    $itemName = '';
    $realCost = 0;
    $realCostArr = array();
    $totalCalEArr = array();

    foreach ($projectTaskIds as $key => $projectTaskId) {

        // echo $projectTaskId['id'];
        // echo "<br>";
        $calB = 0;
        $calC = 0;
        
        $itemtotal = 0;
        $items = get_items_by_type('task', $projectTaskId['id']);
        if($items && count($items) > 0){
            $itemNo = 1;
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
                $itemtotal += ($item["rate"]*$item["qty"]);
                $itemName .= '<div>'.$itemNo.'.'.$item["description"].' <b>('.round($item["qty"]).')</b>'.'</div>';
                $itemNo++;
            }
        }
            
         // =============== the code that doesn't work ============
        $calF = get_task_user_hourly_rate($assignees_id[0]); // hourly_rate
        $calG = get_task_custom_billable_amount($aRow['id']);
        
        $calE = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);
        if(isset($aRow['task_item_percentage'])){
            $calE = ((round($itemtotal + ((($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))))
                      *($aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)))
                +(round($itemtotal + (($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60)))); // additionalPriceTotal
         
        }
        
        $totalCalEArr[] = $calE;
        
        if($totalCalEArr && count($totalCalEArr) > 0){
            $totalsCalEaMount = 0;
            foreach ($totalCalEArr as $key => $totalvalue) {
                $totalsCalEaMount += $totalvalue;
            }
        }
        // =============== the code that doesnt work ============

        $realTime += get_calc_task_real_logged_time($projectTaskId['id']);
        $calB = get_task_custom_billable_amount($projectTaskId['id']);
        
        if($aRow['task_item_percentage']){
            $calC = ((round($itemtotal + ((($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))))*($aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)))+(round($itemtotal + (($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60)))); // additionalPriceTotal
        } else {
            $calC = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);
        }

        $estimateCost += round($itemtotal+($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60)); 
        $realCost = round($itemtotal+$calB);
        
//           if($calC = 0){  $realCost = round($itemtotal+$calB);} else { $realCost = round($itemtotal+$calB+$calC);
// }
        $realCostArr[] = $realCost;

    }
    if($realCostArr && count($realCostArr) > 0){
        $realCostAmount = 0;
        foreach ($realCostArr as $key => $reslcostvalue) {
            $realCostAmount += $reslcostvalue;
        }
    }
}

$outputName = '';
$relName = '';
$row[] = $loop;

if ($aRow['rel_name']) {
    $relName = task_rel_name($aRow['rel_name'], $aRow['rel_id'], $aRow['rel_type']);
    $link = task_rel_link($aRow['rel_id'], $aRow['rel_type']);
    $relName = '<span class="hide"> - </span><a class="text-muted task-table-related" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . _l('task_related_to') . '" href="' . $link . '">' . $relName . '</a>';
}

$row[] = $relName;
$row[] = count($projectTaskIds);
$row[] = $itemName;
$row[] = $aRow['task_duration']*count($projectTaskIds);
$row[] = round($realTime/60);
$row[] = round($estimateCost);
$row[] = round($realCostAmount);
$row[] = '';
$row[] = $totalCalEArr; // display as array or 
//$row[] = $totalsCalEaMount; //to display as a sum
$output['aaData'][] = $row;
$loop++;
}
```

And if you need more details you can find a guide how to use it: http://amco.ro/pdf/Error%20presentation.pdf

Comment: The result have to be - 919.8 / 0 / 84?

Comment: If you look in here: http://amco.ro/pdf/Error%20presentation.pdf the results must be 919.8 from first task and 102.2 from 2nd task

Comment: `$calA` is equal to `$calF` ? Second it don't get this - `$calE = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);` first you add `$itemtotal` and after that you remvoe it.

Comment: ```$calG = get_task_custom_billable_amount($aRow['id']);
        
  $calE = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);
        if(isset($aRow['task_item_percentage'])){
            $calE = ((round($itemtotal + ((($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))))*($aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)))+(round($itemtotal + (($calF * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60)))); // additionalPriceTotal
         
        }```  
I did this but still not working

Comment: dump the data one by one.. like this `task_id - some value/another value and etc.` and see what si wrong

Comment: unefortunately for me I don't know exactly how to do that, is there any tutorial somewhere that you can show me ? (on youtube or a site)

Comment: just add in code `var_dump($variable)` .. for example where you think is your erro - `var_dump($realTim); var_dump($calB)` and so on.. watch how variable is change